# Magento 2 : How can you install a Magento2 quickly to last version with sample data with composer

Tags: magento2, installation, composer, sample-data

How can you install a Magento 2 quickly to last version with sample data with composer

Can you install a Magento2 last version with sample data with composer?

Comment: "how quickly"? What kind of answer to you expect to that? It depends on the speed of your internet connection.

Comment: Hey Dude, "php bin/magento setup:install ..." this is quickly, not in browser

Comment: Oh, you meant "how can you install Magento2 quickly" - sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: It's ok now ? @fschmengler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run command to bring Magento2 from the repository:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento
```

Add the credential for Username and Password for authentification on the terminal, your credential is in your Magento.com account after you logged in click [here](https://marketplace.magento.com/customer/accessKeys/).

---

After ruling the composer command you have to enter in the magento folder that was created by the composer

```
cd magento
```

Add Magento2 Sample Data with composer:

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

Add the credential for Username and Password for authentification on the terminal, your credential is in your Magento.com account after you logged in click [here](https://marketplace.magento.com/customer/accessKeys/).

---

Create database and completes below with the following command:
database name, database user, database password, domain, First Name, Last Name, Email address, user admin, admin password, admin path

Then rule the command for install Magento2 in terminal:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://domain.com/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=db_name --db-user=db_user --db-password=db_pass --admin-firstname=FirstName --admin-lastname=LastName --admin-email=email@domain.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=password --language=en_US --backend-frontname=admin --use-sample-data --magento-init-params=“MAGE_MODE=developer”
```

---

And now you can enjoy Magento2.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed *m2install* tool for such purpose.

- Generate your auth keys and put them into file ~/.composer/auth.json [see more details](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html)
- Run from command line: 
  `m2install.sh -s composer -v 2.1.3 --sample-data yes`

Link on GitHub project: https://github.com/yvoronoy/m2install